# Struggling with Datacontext of a Checkbox in a Listview - Mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

have a look at my code:

```
<Window x:Name="window"
    x:Class="Hmi.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hmi.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
    xmlns:konv="clr-namespace:Hmi.Konverter"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:draw="clr-namespace:System.Drawing;assembly=System.Drawing"
    Title="cHauptFenster"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <konv:cConvIconToImage x:Key="KonvIconImage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="titel" Text="Roboter Gui" FontSize="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" Height="69" Width="800"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label x:Name="Port" Content="Port:" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbPort" Width="66" ItemsSource="{Binding cSerial.aPort,Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding cSerial.sPort,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="#FF707070" />
            <Button x:Name="btnPortAktualisieren" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding cSerial.PortAktualisierenKommando}" Height="25" Width="25">
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Refresh" Spin="False"/>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="btnVerbinden" Command="{Binding cSerial.PortOeffnenKommando}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="25" >
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding cSerial.nVerbindungsStatus, FallbackValue=LanDisconnect}"  Spin="False" />
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cSerial.bPortGeoffnet}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cSerial.bPortGeoffnet}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDDDDD" />
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Verbinden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="lvPunkte" ItemsSource="{Binding cPunkte.aPunkte,Mode=OneWay}" Height="290" IsEnabled="{Binding cSerial.bPortGeoffnet}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="[]" Width="30" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=CheckboxCheckCommand}"
                                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=CheckboxUnheckCommand}"
                                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                </CheckBox>
                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="X" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fX}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Y" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fY}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Z" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fZ}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Rz" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fRx}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ry" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fRy}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Rz" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fRz}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The Datacontext of the Checkbox is at cPunkt which is the class of my Collection(ObservableCollection<*cPunkt*> aPunkte).
I haven't understood yet. Why is the datacontext not my MainViewModel and what do I have to do that becomes this?
I would be happy to receive any other suggestions for improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the CheckBox is within a DataTemplate, it gets the data context of its parent - The `ItemSource` of the `ListView` in this case - unless specifically overridden.  You can adjust the source context for the binding by adding a `DataContext` attribute to the checkbox as in:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext}">
```

or you could:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainViewModel}">
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for